# FacebookShare 0.3.2 Swift ShareDialog console error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-share

I am trying to show the Facebook ShareDialog using FacebookShare Swift SDK 0.3.2 not FBSDKShareKit with the below function in a presented view controller

```
import FacebookShare

func facebookShare() {
            let photo = Photo(image: image, userGenerated: true)
            let myContent = PhotoShareContent(photos: [photo])
            let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
            shareDialog.presentingViewController = self
            shareDialog.mode = .automatic
            shareDialog.completion = { result in
                    print("- in completion")
            }
            do {
            try shareDialog.show()
            } catch {
                    print(error)
            }
```

I am getting this error in the console.

> 2018-09-03 16:12:11.235865+0100 APPNAME[1865:386979] FBSDKLog: param {
>       "advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 0;
>       "anon_id" = "XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX";
>       "application_tracking_enabled" = 1;
>       "custom_events" = "[{\"_ui\":\"no_ui\",\"_eventName\":\"fb_dialog_share_result\",\"_logTime\":1535987524,\"fb_dialog_outcome_error_message\":\"Error
>   Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 \\"(null)\\"
>   UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Must have
>   an asset, image, or imageURL value.,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=photo}\",\"fb_dialog_outcome\":\"Failed\",\"_implicitlyLogged\":\"1\"}]";
>       event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
>       extinfo = "[\"i2\",\"com.APPNAME\",\"1\",\"1.0\",\"11.4.1\",\"iPhone8,4\",\"en_GB\",\"BST\",\"Three\",320,568,\"2.00\",2,60,46,\"Europe\/London\"]";
>       "url_schemes" = "[\"fbapiXXXXXXX\",\"fbXXXXXXXXX\",\"twitterkit-sasasasasasasa\",\"com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX\"]";
>   }

Although the error says:

> Must have an asset, image, or imageURL value.

I have confirmed a UIImage is within the myContent let passed to the ShareDialog with breakpoints.

Comment: An issue has been raised on GitHub:https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the FacebookSDK which has been raised here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/264

Temporary workaround until fix, remove Facebook pods from pod file and add the below, then run pod install.

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '0.3.1'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.3.1'
pod 'FacebookShare', '0.3.1'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.35.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.35.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.35.0'
```